# Convert this null check to java 8 Optional

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I am unable to understand how to remove the below null check by using Java 8 `Optional`

```
for (A objA : listOfObjectsA) {
    if (objA.getStringField() == null) continue;
        // some code to do if not null
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use `Optional`s for that. You can filter the `null` elements using a `Stream`:

```
listOfObjectsA.stream()
              .filter(objA -> objA.getStringField() != null)
              .forEach (... do something  ...);
```

To use `Optional` you can write `Optional.ofNullable(objA.getStringField()).isPresent()`, but that seems pointless.

Comment: Thank you, but even in the above code there is the null check present? So seems like null check is unavoidable in this scenario.

Comment: I posted my comment before you made the edit. Thank you

Comment: @Saad If you wrap the value that might be null with an `Optional`, you can perform actions on it without directly checking for null, but whether or not it makes sense depends on the specific use case.

Comment: You can use `Optional.stream()` in combination with `flatMap` - still pointless but less pointless than `filter` with `isPresent`.

Answer (score 2):

You could replace your code with *Java8* style with streams and `Optional`. But I presonally think that in this concrete case, this is not better that POJO (which is much more simplier and readable):

```
Optional.ofNullable(listOfObjectsA).orElse(Collections.emptyList()).stream()
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .filter(objA -> Objects.nonNull(objA.getStringField()))
        .forEach(objA -> {
            // some code to do if not null
        });
```

If you're sure, that given list cannot be `null` and each element `objA` cannot be `null` as well, then you can definitely avoid some useless checks in this case:

```
listOfObjectsA.stream()
        .filter(objA -> Objects.nonNull(objA.getStringField()))
        .forEach(objA -> {
            // some code to do if not null
        });
```

Comment: isn't that too complicated than simple `filter` and `forEach`?

Comment: @nullpointer Yes, I think so. In this situation, I like POJO with `if..else` more

Answer (score 2):

if "some code to do if not null" only operates on `objA.getStringField()` then you can do:

```
listOfObjectsA.stream()
              .map(A::getStringField)
              .filter(Objects::nonNull)
              .forEach(e -> ...);
```

However, if you still want to have access to the `A` elements then as the other answers have shown you have no choice but to perform an explicit `objA.getStringField() != null`:

```
listOfObjectsA.stream()
              .filter(a -> a.getStringField() != null)
              .forEach(a -> ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally without optional, you can do

```
listOfObjectsA.stream().filter(objA -> objA.getStringField() != null)
                       .forEach(objA -> { /* some code to do if not null*/ });
```